# Passing class member function return value by reference in C++

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers

I've been searching for a solution to this problem but can't seem to find one. I'm sure this general question has been asked before somewhere but hopefully you can help with my specific situation...

I have a class template `someClass` that contain the following (private) members:

```
int     size_x;
int     size_y;
int     size_total;
T *     grid;
```

`someClass` contains a constructor that looks like this:

```
someClass (const int x, const int y)
: size_x (x), size_y (y), size_total (x*y)
{
    grid = new T [size_total];
}
```

a copy constructor that looks like this:

```
someClass (const someClass & rhs)
{
    size_x = rhs.size_x;
    size_y = rhs.size_y;
    size_total = rhs.size_total;
    grid = new T [size_total];
    memcpy(grid, rhs.grid, size_total*sizeof(T));
}
```

a member function that looks like this:

```
T * retGrid (void) const
{
    return grid;
}
```

and an assignment operator that looks like this:

```
someClass & operator= (const someClass & rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        size_x = rhs.size_x;
        size_y = rhs.size_y;
        size_total = rhs.size_total;
        grid = new T [size_total];
        memcpy(grid, rhs.grid, size_total*sizeof(T));
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I'm trying to pass the following two `someClass` objects

```
someClass<double> *I1 = new someClass<double>(10,10);

someClass<double> I2 = *I1;
```

to a function outside of the `someClass` class with the following prototype:

```
int someFunction(double *arr);
```

This call works fine:

```
int status;
status = someFunction(I1->retGrid()); // Properly working function call
```

but this does not

```
status = someFunction(&I2.retGrid()); // Compiler gives error that says "error: invalid lvalue in unary &"
```

And if I call `someFunction` like this:

```
status = someFunction(I2.retGrid()); // Compiler gives no error but function returns error value in status
```

the code compiles but I get a run-time error (a bad status value from another function call within `someFunction`).

How can I properly pass `I2` to `someFunction`?

Many thanks...

Comment: You need to define a copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I do have a copy constructor in my code but I left it out of this post. I edited the post to include it now.

Comment: Can you check the contents of I2 (e.g. dump them out or examine in a debugger)? Has it been correctly copied from I1? (I am guessing that your "bad status value" might reflect the content of the passed double array in some way.)

Comment: The copy constructor exhibits undefined behavior for all instantiations of the template in which `T` is non-POD. You should replace the `memcpy` with a call to `std::copy(rhs.grid, rhs.grid+rhs.size_total, grid)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to take address of the temporary object (in this case, a pointer but this doesn't really matter)  returned by `retGrid`. Hence you cannot use the `&` approach.

Without the ampersand, you would pass the internal array from `I2` to `someFunction`. If that's not fine for you (i.e. since you get some kind of runtime error), consider making a copy of this array and passing it to `someFunction` instead.

Comment: Thanks Xion...what is your suggestion for the best way to make a copy to pass to `someFunction`?

Comment: @Evan: You can't pass a raw array like this, and ever expect to get a copy automatically without some sort of intermediate step.  You can pass your class directly, or you can manually copy your array and pass the copy.

Answer (score 1):

When you have pointers in your class and you have to allocate memory for each object, you need to define a copy constructor and an assignment operator. You only added the later. This initialization

```
someClass<double> I2 = *I1;
```

is actually performed with a copy constructor, not with the assignment operator. It is identical to

```
someClass<double> I2(*I1);
```

However, it is wrong, because you only allocate memory for grid. But if grid was already allocated (from a previous assignment) you'd leak memory. So it should look like this:

```
someClass & operator= (const someClass & rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        size_x = rhs.size_x;
        size_y = rhs.size_y;
        size_total = rhs.size_total;
        delete [] grid;
        grid = new T [size_total];
        memcpy(grid, rhs.grid, size_total*sizeof(T));
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. I included the copy constructor in my post. I originally excluded it but it was in my code.

Comment: This implementation of the assignment operator is wrong, and will leave the object in an inconsistent state (such that the destructor cannot be called) if anything in the expression `new T[...]` throws an exception (and you can't exclude `bad_alloc`, regardless of T).

Comment: yes, of course, but that is the same for any kind of memory allocation

Comment: I think James' (valid) point is that showing broken code in an answer isn't as helpful as it could be.

Comment: @ildjam Exactly.  I actually hesitated about voting it down, because the proposed solution is broken, even if the point raised about the initial implementation is valid.

Answer (score 1):

First question: why aren't use using `std::vector`, instead of
trying to manage the memory yourself.  You don't show the
destructor; I presume you free the memory there.  But there are
still problems:

- In the copy constructor, you use `memcpy`.  That's not a problem
  when you instantiate over `double`, but it could be a problem
  for other types.  You should be using `std::copy`.
- If you were using `std::vector`, and `retGrid` still needed to
  return a `T*`, it would be `return &grid[0];`.
- The assignment operator is broken.  It leaks any previous
  memory, and if the `new` fails, it leaves the object in an
  inconsistent state.  (Having to check for self-assignment is
  usually a hint that something is wrong.)  A correct assignment
  operator will do all operations which might fail before changing
  anything in the object.  You might search for information about
  the swap idiom, but something like the following would also
  work:

.

```
SomeClass&
SomeClass<T>::operator=( SomeClass const& other )
{
    T* newGrid = new T[other.size_total];
    std::copy( other.grid, other.grid + other.size_total, newGrid );
    delete [] grid;
    size_x = other.size_x;
    size_y = other.size_y;
    size_total = other.size_total;
    grid = newGrid;
    return *this;
}
```

You might want to optimize this if the `size_total` are equal
(or `size_total <= other.size_total`).

And of course, if you use `std::vector`, the compiler generated
assignment operator and copy constructor are sufficient; you
don't have to write anything.

- Is there any reason why you use a pointer for `I1`?  (Or is
  this just an artifact of a larger context from which you
  extracted the code?)
- Concerning `someFunction( &I2.retGrid() );`,
  `someClass::retGrid()` returns a pointer.  Regardless of whether
  you call the function through a pointer or an object.  Taking
  the address results in a `T**`.
- Concerning the last call, there is nothing that would cause
  a problem here in the code you've shown us.  As long as `I2` is
  in scope and hasn't deleted it's object, there should be no
  problem.  This is the correct way of calling the function on an
  object.  The problem in your code is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the runtime error that you are getting but `status = someFunction(&I2.retGrid());` is passing pointer to a temporary object.

The runtime error could be because of missing copy constructor that is invoked in `someClass<double> I2 = *I1;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the extremely useful comments, especially those by AAT, David Rodriguez - dribeas, James Kanze, and Marius Bancila.

It turns out the problem was improper interface with a third-party function inside `someFunction`. I found and fixed the error after some sleep and now the call:

```
status = someFunction(I2.retGrid()); // Compiler gives no error but function returns error value in status
```

works correctly.

But this discussion brought other very important related issues to light, namely the memory management issues related to my copy constructor and assignment operator and suggested use of vectors. I believe this thread has a lot of value on those merits.