# Create a class function with call-by-reference return value in C++

Tags: c++, class

For one of my cpp-programs I created some classes (as usual, variables in the private part, and functions for accessing in the public part). But now I have the problem, that I want to access several variables in this class by reference, e.g. if I get them via `getVariable(void)`, I want to directly modify them. I already wrote a second function called `setVariable(value)`. But this function is only usable if I only want to write into the variable.
How can I solve the problem that I can read and write in a private variable which is returned by a public class function?
I already read these questions: [Passing class member function return value by reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071896/passing-class-member-function-return-value-by-reference-in-c) and [Return a reference by a class function and return a whole object in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406020/return-a-reference-by-a-class-function-and-return-a-whole-object-in-c), but they don't suit for my problem.

Example:

```
class A  
{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        int getX(void);
        void setX(int y);
}

int A::getX(void)
{
    return A::x;
}

void A::setX(int y)
{
    A::x = y;
}
```

I want to call it like

```
A testA;
testA.setX(2);
testA.getX() = 5; // Ok, seems a bit strange, but some of my other functions require that...
//A::x is now 5
std::cout << testA.getX();//Output is 5
```

Is that possible? Or should I rather rewrite the other functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function returning private member by reference to be able to modify it, as in example:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        A(): a(2) {}
        int & mutableA() { return a;}
        void printA() { std::cout << this->a << std::endl; }
};



int main()
{
    A instance;
    instance.printA();
    instance.mutableA() += 2;
    instance.printA();
}
```

If you run this program, the output will be:

```
2
4
```

In the example above, we modify member `a` using function `mutableA()` (initialy it has a value of 2, afterwards it's 4). Crucial element is `int &` return declaration in function, which tells the compiler, that function will return reference, which allows us to modify original, private variable.

As a sidenote, I would say that this isn't very common pracitce - of course there are reasons to do it, but it might be the case that you don't want `a` to be private in the first place if you are planning to modify it from outside the class. It obviously depends on your design, but it's something worth considering.

Comment: Some of my further functions require a `&x` as argument, and I don't want to alter them (would lead to a complete restructuration of the program).

Comment: Well, then this should solve your problem. I included the sidenote also for all people that might read this answer while googling your problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a reference which can be used for modification:

```
thing & get_member() {return member;}
```

You'll also want a `const` overload, so you can still get it from a `const` object, but not change it:

```
thing const & get_member() const {return member;}
```

But if you want to be able to read and write it without restrictions, why is it private in the first place?

Comment: Because I only want access to it via this function, nothing else.

Comment: @arc_lupus: OK, but exposing it via a reference has no advantages over exposing it directly. All you're doing is making the code slightly larger and slightly more annoying to work with.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but at the moment I don't want to go through all the code and rewrite everything, so I am doing it step by step...